# xslt namespace issue rss

Tags: xml, xslt, rss

I am trying to transform the feed of [bank of canada](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/assets/rates_rss/noon/en_all.xml) to use it in my app.

Here is my xml and my xsl: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2D4/4

I can't change the xml, this is a rss feed. The only line that blocks me is this one:

```
xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
```

If I delete this one, my selector is good and I get the result. I am a beginner in xslt. Can someone explain me what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
 xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
```

says that all unqualified element names like RDF, item, title in the XML have the given namespace. In order to **match** these elements you need the same namespace definition in your XSLT and inclue the namespace prefix in your XPath expressions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:rss="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
    exclude-result-prefixes = "rss">

<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/rss:RDF/rss:item"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rss:item">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="rss:title"/><br/>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="description"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```